# How do I stop the background music in the arcade library?

Tags: python, audio, arcade

I need the music to play until the game is over, at which point I'd like it to stop, but nothing I try seems to work.
Below is the shortened version of the code I'm working with. If anything, the sound should stop playing immediately because `self.game` is set to False in the update right away, but no matter what I try the music keeps playing.

````
import arcade


SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_TITLE = "Game"


class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        self.game = True
        self.music = arcade.load_sound("soundtrack.wav")

    def setup(self):
        self.music.play()

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)

    def update(self, delta_time):
        self.game = False
        if not self.game:
            # stop the music
            ???


window = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
window.setup()
arcade.run()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple sound control example:

```
import arcade


class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(400, 300, 'Sound demo')
        self.text = 'stop'
        self.music = arcade.load_sound(':resources:music/funkyrobot.mp3')
        self.media_player = self.music.play()

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(text=f'Click to {self.text} music', start_x=200, start_y=150, anchor_x='center', font_size=16)

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        if self.text == 'stop':
            self.text = 'start'
            self.media_player.pause()
        else:
            self.text = 'stop'
            self.media_player.play()

Game()
arcade.run()
```

Sound turns on/off when clicking:

[image: Sound example]

Answer (score 0):

use arcade.stop_sound(your_sound_player) to stop the sound being played by a player.